# OpenLayers 3 XYZ layer issues with OpenRailwayMap

Tags: layers, openlayers-2, api, xyz

[Code with issue on Codepen](http://codepen.io/ferret/pen/GpbRZR) - Having successfully integrated the OpenRailwayMap API into Leaflet, I wanted to use OpenLayers instead and followed the API instructions, but am getting an error: " Cannot read property 'XYZ' of undefined". Can anyone see the issue here?

Comment: You are using OpenLayers2 Code in OpenLayers 3. Try to create a TileSource with ol.source.XYZ like in this example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/xyz.html

Answer (score 1):

In your example you using OpenLayers3. In OL3 there is no `OpenLayer.Layer.XYZ`

But you can create your Layer with:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: ['<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a>, Style: <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA 2.0</a> <a href="http://www.openrailwaymap.org/">OpenRailwayMap</a> and OpenStreetMap'],
        url: 'http://{a-c}.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        tileSize: 512 //<- the ORM tiles are 512*512 Pixel
    })
});
```